# R Find Total count broken down by Visit ID

Tags: r, dplyr

In R, I have a dataframe:

```
df <- read_delim("Visit_ID | Visit_Count | Cluster  
A  | 2 | orange    
A  | 2 | green
B  | 2 | green  
B  | 2 | green    
C  | 3 | orange    
C  | 3 | orange    
C  | 3 | green    
D  | 3 | orange  
D  | 3 | green    
D  | 3 | orange", delim = "|", trim_ws = TRUE)
```

How I would like to get a breakdown of each Cluster's Visit_ID count by visit frequency. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
df_result <- read_delim("Cluster | VisitID_Frequency | Total_count  
Orange  | 1 | 1    
Orange  | 2 | 2
Orange  | 3 | 0
Green   | 1 | 3
Green   | 2 | 1
Green   | 3 | 0
", delim = "|", trim_ws = TRUE)
```

Comment: Could you explain with more detail how is the expected result obtained or calculated?

Comment: Is the expected output values correct (based on the input showed)

Answer (score 0):

```
df %>% group_by(Visit_ID, Cluster) %>% 
                summarise(visit_count = n()) %>% 
                  arrange(Cluster) %>% 
                    group_by(Cluster, visit_count) %>% 
                      count()
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.